# How to make time delay for Splash screen in ionic applications

Tags: angular, ionic3

Hi i am new for Ionic app development and i am trying to do regular thing what we  do in every app,I want to show splash screen with some time delay and then if user already login have to go **HOME** page if not have to move **LOGIN** page for this i wrote below code but i am not understand how to make time delay and how to move one page to another page based on user login status can some on help me please

### code:-

```
constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
            platform.ready().then(() => {

        statusBar.styleDefault();
        splashScreen.hide();


       this.storage.get('userLoged').then(status=>{
          var userInfo = JSON.parse(status);
          if(userInfo.status=== 'login'){
            //Move to HOME page
          }else{
            //Move to LOGIN page
          }
        });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change splash screen delay by changing the value in

`<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />`

inside `config.xml` file.

You can navigate through pages using a ViewChild of your nav component (already exists if you haven't changed the default app.component ts file):

```
@ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
```

so it will be

```
this.storage.get('userLoged').then(status=>{
      var userInfo = JSON.parse(status);
      if(userInfo.status=== 'login'){
        this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
      }else{
        this.nav.setRoot(LoginPage);
      }
    });
```

wherever you want in app.component. 
There is a service that you can use if you want to navigate from one page to another but in app component you need to use the nav component.

Comment: how to finish this activity ,I mean user press back button we should not show splash screen, we have to close the app

Comment: can you please edit my code because i am not understand piece by piece code

Comment: @AbhiRam Back button will exit the app if there is no other page left in the page stack. You can use platform service's exitApp() method if you need any other behavior

Comment: how can i Remove a view from the back history,i mean when user tap on back button should not show splash screen have to kill the app

Comment: splashScreen.hide(); method is hide splash screen?,In my case this method calling is necessary?

Comment: @AbhiRam Yes it is.

Comment: but in my case have to splash screen some minutes if we use splashScreen.hide(); it will be hide right?

Comment: @AbhiRam My bad you don't actually need to manually hide it if it has a delay